# How to fix incorrect position I get when dispatching an update to ListUpdateCallback using DiffUtil

Tags: java, android, android-diffutils

I have an Android application where the user can modify multiple `String` items using `EditText` at the same time, so I need to figure out what have changed in order to notify the server about the changes (create new item, update existing item or delete the latter), that is why I am using `DiffUtil` with `ListUpdateCallback` to do that. The problem that if the old list has size of 2 items; and I removed the item at index 0, then added 3 items to the end of the list, I get a callback to `onInserted` with incorrect position paramter which leads to `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, *(and it is the behavior of removing any item in the old list except for the last one)* please take a look at this [GIF that shows the problem](https://ibb.co/TRbfGsQ).

I have tried the following code with other changes made to the new list like removing at index 1 and then adding 3 items to end of the list and it works fine!

The array I am working with is of type Answer which is a class:

```
public class Answer {
    private String id;
    private String questionId;
    private String text;
    private Integer count;
}
```

Please note that 2 different objects could be identified by the id, if two items the same; then the content could be identified by the text.

DiffUtil.Callback

```
public class AnswersDiffCallback extends DiffUtil.Callback {

    List<Answer> newAnswers;
    List<Answer> oldAnswers;

    public AnswersDiffCallback(List<Answer> newAnswers, List<Answer> oldAnswers) {
        this.newAnswers = newAnswers;
        this.oldAnswers = oldAnswers;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOldListSize() {
        return oldAnswers == null ? 0 : oldAnswers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getNewListSize() {
        return newAnswers == null ? 0 : newAnswers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        Answer oldAnswer = oldAnswers.get(oldItemPosition);
        Answer newAnswer = newAnswers.get(newItemPosition);
        return Objects.equals(oldAnswer.getId(), newAnswer.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        Answer oldAnswer = oldAnswers.get(oldItemPosition);
        Answer newAnswer = newAnswers.get(newItemPosition);
        return Objects.equals(oldAnswer.getText(), newAnswer.getText());
    }
}
```

in ListUpdateCallback I am trying to log the callbacks I get in order to test if it is working before I talk to the server.

```
Log.d(TAG, "answers: oldAnswers = " + Utils.serializeObject(oldAnswers));
Log.d(TAG, "answers: newAnswers = " + Utils.serializeObject(newAnswers));
Log.d(TAG, "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new AnswersDiffCallback(newAnswers, oldAnswers), true);
diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(new ListUpdateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onInserted(int position, int count) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("onInserted: (position, count) = (%d, %d)", position, count));
            for (int i = position; i < position + count; i++) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onInserted: newAnswer.text = " + newAnswers.get(i).getText());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onInserted: Exception", ex);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoved(int position, int count) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRemoved: (position, count) = (" + position + ", " + count + ")");
            for (int i = position; i < position + count; i++) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("onRemoved: (oldAnswer.id, oldAnswer.text) = (%s, %s)", oldAnswers.get(i).getId(), oldAnswers.get(i).getText()));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onRemoved: Exception", ex);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "onMoved: (fromPosition, toPosition) = (" + fromPosition + ", " + toPosition + ")");
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("onMoved: (oldAnswer.id, oldAnswer.text) = (%s, %s)", oldAnswers.get(fromPosition).getId(), oldAnswers.get(fromPosition).getText()));
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("onMoved: (newAnswer.id, newAnswer.text) = (%s, %s)", newAnswers.get(toPosition).getId(), newAnswers.get(toPosition).getText()));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onMoved: Exception", ex);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }

    @Override
    public void onChanged(int position, int count, @Nullable Object payload) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: (position, count) = (" + position + ", " + count + ")");
            for (int i = position; i < position + count; i++) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("onChanged: (oldAnswer.id, oldAnswer.text) = (%s, %s)", oldAnswers.get(i).getId(), oldAnswers.get(i).getText()));
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("onChanged: (newAnswer.id, newAnswer.text) = (%s, %s)", newAnswers.get(i).getId(), newAnswers.get(i).getText()));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onChanged: Exception", ex);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
});
```

and here is the logcat with the exception I have got:

```
2019-06-19 16:32:00.461 24515-24515/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: answers: oldAnswers = [{"count":0,"id":"5d09a1236969e249cca42e96","questionId":"5d09a1236969e249cca42e95","text":"old answer 0"},{"count":0,"id":"5d09a1236969e249cca42e97","questionId":"5d09a1236969e249cca42e95","text":"old answer 1"}]
2019-06-19 16:32:00.501 24515-24515/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: answers: newAnswers = [{"count":0,"id":"5d09a1236969e249cca42e97","questionId":"5d09a1236969e249cca42e95","text":"old answer 1"},{"text":"new answer 0"},{"text":"new answer 1"},{"text":"new answer 2"}]
2019-06-19 16:32:00.501 24515-24515/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-06-19 16:35:19.550 24515-24515/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: onInserted: (position, count) = (2, 3)
2019-06-19 16:35:19.550 24515-24515/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: onInserted: newAnswer.text = new answer 1
2019-06-19 16:35:19.550 24515-24515/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: onInserted: newAnswer.text = new answer 2
2019-06-19 16:35:19.599 24515-24515/com.example.myApp E/AdminQuestionsFragment: onInserted: Exception
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.example.myApp.views.AdminQuestionsFragment$5.onInserted(AdminQuestionsFragment.java:333)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.BatchingListUpdateCallback.dispatchLastEvent(BatchingListUpdateCallback.java:61)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.BatchingListUpdateCallback.onRemoved(BatchingListUpdateCallback.java:96)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil$DiffResult.dispatchRemovals(DiffUtil.java:921)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil$DiffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(DiffUtil.java:836)
        at com.example.myApp.views.AdminQuestionsFragment.lambda$onActivityResult$8$AdminQuestionsFragment(AdminQuestionsFragment.java:320)
        at com.example.myApp.views.-$$Lambda$AdminQuestionsFragment$KZmQo8gdnjCYX1JsaACEVkjSd1s.onChanged(Unknown Source:8)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:113)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:126)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged(LiveData.java:424)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver.onStateChanged(LiveData.java:376)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:361)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:188)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(LiveData.java:185)
        at com.example.myApp.views.AdminQuestionsFragment.onActivityResult(AdminQuestionsFragment.java:387)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:170)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7454)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4353)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4402)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2019-06-19 16:35:19.599 24515-24515/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-06-19 16:35:19.600 24515-24515/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: onRemoved: (position, count) = (0, 1)
2019-06-19 16:35:19.603 24515-24515/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: onRemoved: (oldAnswer.id, oldAnswer.text) = (5d09a1236969e249cca42e96, old answer 0)
2019-06-19 16:35:19.603 24515-24515/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the problem is with this line:

```
2019-06-19 16:35:19.550 24515-24515/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: onInserted: (position, count) = (2, 3)
```

why the position is not 1?

**Update 1**
here is the logcat if I have old list of 2 items and I removed the item at index 1 then added 3 items to the end of the list:

```
2019-06-19 18:25:24.368 28118-28118/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: answers: oldAnswers = [{"count":0,"id":"5d09a1236969e249cca42e96","questionId":"5d09a1236969e249cca42e95","text":"old answer 0"},{"count":0,"id":"5d09a1236969e249cca42e97","questionId":"5d09a1236969e249cca42e95","text":"old answer 1"}]
2019-06-19 18:25:24.370 28118-28118/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: answers: newAnswers = [{"count":0,"id":"5d09a1236969e249cca42e96","questionId":"5d09a1236969e249cca42e95","text":"old answer 0"},{"text":"new answer 0"},{"text":"new answer 1"},{"text":"new answer 2"}]
2019-06-19 18:25:24.370 28118-28118/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-06-19 18:25:24.370 28118-28118/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: onRemoved: (position, count) = (1, 1)
2019-06-19 18:25:24.371 28118-28118/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: onRemoved: (oldAnswer.id, oldAnswer.text) = (5d09a1236969e249cca42e97, old answer 1)
2019-06-19 18:25:24.371 28118-28118/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-06-19 18:25:24.372 28118-28118/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: onInserted: (position, count) = (1, 3)
2019-06-19 18:25:24.372 28118-28118/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: onInserted: newAnswer.text = new answer 0
2019-06-19 18:25:24.372 28118-28118/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: onInserted: newAnswer.text = new answer 1
2019-06-19 18:25:24.372 28118-28118/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: onInserted: newAnswer.text = new answer 2
2019-06-19 18:25:24.372 28118-28118/com.example.myApp D/AdminQuestionsFragment: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a known issue for ListUpdateCallback. It is not possible within `onInserted` for the inserted oldList item to identify its related position in the newList.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115701827

My solution for this is: Insert a null-dummy list item in the oldList, and after `diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo` is done, replace the null-dummies with the newList items at same positions.

Example, I have left some debugging code and logs to identify the problem:

```
    public static final class ListUpdate<T extends BaseIdentifier> implements ListUpdateCallback {

    private final List<T> oldList;
    private final List<T> newList;

    public ListUpdate(@NonNull List<T> oldList, @NonNull List<T> newList) {
        //logger.trace("ListUpdate" + System.lineSeparator()  + "old={}" + System.lineSeparator() + "new={}", BaseIdentifier.toString(oldList), BaseIdentifier.toString(newList));

        this.oldList = oldList;
        this.newList = newList;
    }

    public int inserts = 0;

    public boolean hasInserts() {
        return inserts > 0;
    }

    public void finishInserts() {
        if (inserts <= 0) {
            return;
        }

        //logger.trace("finishInserts inserts={}", inserts);

        ListIterator<T> oldListIterator = oldList.listIterator();
        ListIterator<T> newListIterator = newList.listIterator();

        while (inserts > 0 && oldListIterator.hasNext() && newListIterator.hasNext()) {
            T oldItem = oldListIterator.next();
            T newItem = newListIterator.next();

            if (oldItem == null) {
                //Replaces the last element returned by next()
                oldListIterator.set((T) newItem.copy());
                inserts--;
            }
        }

        if (inserts > 0 || oldList.contains(null)) {
            //There must be something wrong
            logger.error("finishInserts inserts={} remaining", inserts);
        }
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void onInserted(int position, int count) {
        //logger.trace("onInserted position={} count={}", position, count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            /*
            T item = newList.get(position + i);
            oldList.add(position + i, (T) item.copy());
             */
            //We don't know the related position of the newList, so we add null
            oldList.add(position + i, null);
            inserts++;
        }
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void onRemoved(int position, int count) {
        //logger.trace("onRemoved position={} count={}", position, count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            oldList.remove(position);
        }
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void onMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        //logger.trace("onMoved fromPosition={} toPosition={}", fromPosition, toPosition);

        T item = oldList.remove(fromPosition);
        oldList.add(toPosition, item);
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void onChanged(int position, int count, Object payload) {
        logger.trace("onChanged position={} count={}", position, count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            T item = newList.get(position + i);
            //noinspection unchecked
            oldList.set(position + i, (T) item.copy());
        }
    }
}
```

Call like

```
        DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new BaseIdentifier.BaseIdentifierDiffUtilCallback(oldProcessEvents, processEvents));
        BaseIdentifier.ListUpdate<ProcessEvent> updater = new BaseIdentifier.ListUpdate<>(oldProcessEvents, processEvents);
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(updater);
        updater.finishInserts();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = position; i < position + count; i++) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onInserted: newAnswer.text = " + newAnswers.get(i).getText());
}
```

This loop will definitely throw `IndexOutOfBoundError`. `count` is number of items that have been added. and `position` is the position of the new item. When you do `position + count` that would be definitely more than the size of your list at some point. And hence the error.

> The problem that if the old list has size of 2 items; and I removed the item at index 0, then added 3 items to the end of the list

Do you call `dispatchUpdates` after removing and before adding the new items?

I think first it's calculating items that are inserted and then item that is removed and hence the position is 2 in `onInserted`.

You can wrap your `ListUpdateCallback` in `BatchingListUpdateCallback` if you want batched updates.

Comment: why it would throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the position is correct? for example if I inserted 2 items at the beginning of the list then the position should be 0 and count is 2 then the loop would run with these values of `i`: `0, 1` which should not throw any exception. And I did not call `dispatchUpdates` after removing and before adding the new items, I call it only after the new list is fully modified! Please look at the update of the post I have posted an example that works fine!

Comment: After your `Update 1`, what's the issue? It seems to work as expected.

Comment: You said that you first removed item at position 0 (there were 2 items, initially) and then added 3 items at the end. At this point, total items are 4. Now, count is 3 and position is 2 => count + position is 5 which is greater than the size of the list (4).

Since you are performing multiple changes in one dispatch, it is possible that `DiffUtil` calls `onInserted` first and then `onRemoved`. I don't know why or how the exact algorithm is supposed to work.

Comment: Yes, but why position is 2, the other example I posted I removed the item at index 1 then got a callback `onInserted` with the correct position! And please note I am using `i < position + count` not `i <= position + count` so `i` will never be equal to `position + count`.

Comment: DiffUtil uses Myers' diff algorithm - http://blog.robertelder.org/diff-algorithm/ It's complicated so I don't know but it is possible that based on the difference it calls different methods in the order.

Comment: For `Update 1` it works fine but if I remove the item at index 0 it still gives me `IndexOutOfBoundsException`